# matlabFunction, written to file, mishandles variable of integration

Tags: matlab

**Problem**

I'm trying to symbolically differentiate a function with respect to two different variables and then create a function file for each of the derivatives. One of the function files works, the other does not, because `matlabFunction` mishandles the variable of integration.

**My Approach**

The code to generate the function files (the starting function is the (non-regularized) incomplete beta function)

```
syms x y a b fnc dFncda dFncdb
assume (a > 1);
assume (b > 1);
assume (0 < x & x < 1);
fnc(x,a,b) = int(y^(a-1)*(1-y)^(b-1),y,0,x);
dFncda(x,a,b) = diff(fnc(x,a,b),a,1);
dFncdb(x,a,b) = diff(fnc(x,a,b),b,1);
matlabFunction(dFncda(x,a,b),'File','derivA');
matlabFunction(dFncdb(x,a,b),'File','derivB');
```

**Results**

The resulting derivA.m file (excluding auto-generated comments)

```
function out1 = derivA(a,b,x)

out1 = integral(@(y)y.^(a-1.0).*log(y).*(-y+1.0).^(b-1.0),0.0,x);
```

Test from command

```
derivA(0.5,3,3)
ans = 
   -1.7590
```

Next, same thing for derivB.m

```
function out1 = derivB(a,b,x)

t2 = -y+1.0;
out1 = integral(@(y)t2.^(b-1.0).*y.^(a-1.0).*log(t2),0.0,x);
```

Part of the integrand, containing the variable of integration, has been assigned to `t2`.  As the variable of integration is not defined outside of the subsequent anonymous function, this unsurprisingly results in an error

```
derivB(0.5,3,3)
Undefined function or variable 'y'.

Error in derivB
t2 = -y+1.0;
```

**Questions**

Could I do something differently to prevent this (other than simply writing the function file myself)? Is this a bug in the way `matlabFunction` handles integrals? I'm using version '9.2.0.556344 (R2017a)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `'optimize'` flag to force MATLAB to not optimize your function.

```
matlabFunction(dFncdb(x,a,b),'File','derivB','optimize',false);
```

The contents of 'derivB.m' without auto-generated comments is now the same formula as using `disp(dFuncdb)` on your created derivative function:

```
function out1 = derivB(a,b,x)

    out1 = int(y.^(a-1.0).*log(-y+1.0).*(-y+1.0).^(b-1.0),y,0.0,x);
```

For documentation, see [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html#namevaluepairarguments).

In this case, 'optimization' means 'break the function'! So yes, this looks like buggy/unexpected behaviour when `'optimize'` is set to `true` (which is the default).